# Не работает autoplay видео

Tags: html, html5

Есть видео:

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" controlslist="nodownload" autoplay>
    <source src="files/index-en.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Во всех браузерах, кроме IE, не работает автовоспроизведение.
Это какая-то ошибка, или ограничение браузера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй добавить атрибут muted

```
<video id="video" muted controls="controls" controlslist="nodownload" autoplay>
    <source src="files/index-en.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Или же как вариант

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('video').play();
</script>
<video id="video" muted controls="controls" controlslist="nodownload" autoplay>
    <source src="files/index-en.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Ваш метод с muted помог